# Bold text Media player

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have lyrics of a track. I have displayed them in TextView. The problem is, that I want to make the current synced lyrics bold. Suppose the track has a line that says "How far can we go, can we go.". I want to make this sentence bold in my TextView. How can I do that?

Comment: Kindly provide your code and what you have tried

Comment: I dont have any idea how to do this. And i dont have code for this problem

Comment: You have to do research. Search your problem on google.

Comment: As brandall wrote in this answer, there is no native way to convert audio files to text in Android. However, you could use the libraries he suggests in his answer (Nuance and A&T look good to me).

As an alternative, I would use an API to get the lyrics for the song such as chartlyrics.com.

Now you have the lyrics, but syncing them with the song is very difficult. I don't know how to do it and would display the whole lyrics to let the user scroll through.

Comment: oh...you right :)

Comment: You'll need to use a third-party API to do this, such as.

A&T
Nuance
iSpeech
And perhaps Pocket Sphinx, although you may have to write the file input stream side of it yourself.

If you're not concerned about breaking terms and conditions, you could use the Chrome Speech API.

Comment: http://developer.att.com/developer/forward.jsp?passedItemId=12500023

Comment: http://nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php?task=home

Comment: http://www.ispeech.org/